# Como instalar o Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Boa noite à todos os programadores. Ando enfrentando dificuldades pra fazer algo que provavelmente pra alguns deve ser absurdamente fácil, mas não tô conseguindo de jeito nenhum. Que é, instalar e fazer funcionar o Vue.

Já tentei:

```
> npm install -g @vue/cli
```

E aparece:

```
Token não reconhecido no texto de origem.
Em linha:1 caractere:16
+ npm install -g  <<<< @vue/cli
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken
```

já tentei "npm install vue", e ele chega à instalar dependencias, porém ao abrir no live-server ele não roda de jeito nenhum.

Já apaguei tudo e tentei fazer de novo, já tentei aplicar o CDN direto no html...e bom, nada.

o vue via CDN no HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


 
</head>
  <body>
      

<div id="app">

{{ 2+2 }}
{{ text }}

</div>

<!-- o CDN -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>

    <!-- Meu código Vue -->
    
<script>

const app = new Vue = ({

el:'#app',
data: {
  text: 'test'
}


});



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

OBS: Já tentei aplicar o link da cdn na head, que eu havia visto isso em um curso, porém não foi também.
Ao abrir o HTML, fica escrito exatamente o que tá no código. "{{ 2 + 2 }}" sem o resultado 4, e o "{{ text }}" exatamente do mesmo jeito.

Peço por favor uma ajuda de vocês. Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Pelo visto você ainda é iniciante no Vuejs, eu procurava sempre utilizar a instalação via link cdn quando trabalhava com Vue (há tempos) e pude reparar, entre algumas outras coisinhas, que o link que você está utilizando não é o link que atualmente é utilizado no starter da documentação oficial para a versão de desenvolvimento.

Recomendo que você siga o exemplo idêntico ao contido na documentação até mesmo para validar seu ambiente.

A documentação do VueJs é completa e clara, sempre procure seguir os exemplos básicos das documentações em caso de problemas, principalmente no inicio. É possível que você esteja seguindo um curso ou tutorial já desatualizado e por isso os links ou sintaxe não funcionem, por isso o ideal é sempre estar com a documentação 'em måos'.

Segue o link da starter oficial do Vue.js:
https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Bastava aplicar o CDN no campo da tag Head, ao invés de aplicar ao final da Body, como é "normalmente recomendável" para implementações JS. Acredito que seja assim devido à manipulação do Vue com o DOM...mas, enfim, sou novato o suficiente pra estar falando alguma besteira.